# Decidable sqrt function in Z3

Tags: z3

Since [disabling unsound simplification of root objects](https://github.com/Z3Prover/z3/commit/035f2bb0dae81519e550a9c865c2aab93eac2dc2), Z3 will now fail on this simple model involving a square root:

```
(define-fun sqrt ((x Real)) Real (^ x 0.5))
(declare-fun y () Real)
(declare-fun x () Real)
(assert (= y (sqrt x)))
(check-sat)
```

This returns `sat` with Z3 4.4.1, but `unknown` with master.
If I change the problem definition to use `is_sqrt` as defined by Nikolaj in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30328888/use-z3-and-smt-lib-to-define-sqrt-function-with-a-real-number), then Z3 master will return `sat`.  The approach using `is_sqrt` shows that all real roots can be pushed into `QF_NRA` by introducing auxiliary variables, so I think Z3 should be able to solve all problems involving roots over the reals.

How can I define a square-root function in the reals that will result in a decidable theory, assuming the rest of the model is in `QF_NRA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a subtle difference between `(assert (= y (^ x 0.5)))` and `(assert (and (= x (* y y)) (> y 0.0)))`.  The difference comes from the requirement that all functions in Z3 (and SMT-LIB) are total.  This means, for example, that [`y=1/x, x=0` is considered satisfiable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107558/y-1-x-x-0-satisfiable-in-the-reals/38107559).  Given that `^` is total in Z3, `(assert (and (= y (^ x 0.5)) (< x 0.0)))` is considered satisfiable.  We can't convert `(= y (^ x 0.5))` to `(and (= x (* y y)) (> y 0.0))`, because if `x < 0` then the former is considered satisfiable but the latter is unsatisfiable.  Similarly, any `sqrt` function defined within SMT-LIB would also be total, so we cannot define a `sqrt` function by any other means such that `(assert (= y (sqrt x)))` is equivalent to `(assert (and (= x (* y y)) (> y 0.0)))`.  In addition to the above difference as to whether or not `y = sqrt(x), x < 0` (pseudocode) is considered satisfiable, it is also the case that `(assert (and (= x (* y y)) (> y 0.0)))` is decidable (it is in QF_NRA), while `(assert (= y (^ x 0.5)))` is not.

The solution for my purpose is to not use a Z3 or SMT-LIB function definition for the square-root.  Instead, I will use statements of the form `(assert (and (= x (* y y)) (> y 0.0)))` to indicate that `y` is the square-root of `x`.  Such assertions are within QF_NRA, so models built in this way will be decidable.  Furthermore, this has the advantage that `y = sqrt(x), x < 0` (pseudocode) will return `unsat` if it is represented in SMT-LIB via the statements `(assert (and (= x (* y y)) (> y 0.0)))` and `(assert (< x 0.0))`.  To return `unsat` for this example is more in-line with my use case.