# y=1/x, x=0 satisfiable in the reals?

Tags: z3, smt, cvc4

In SMT-LIB:

```
(declare-fun y () Real)
(declare-fun x () Real)
(assert (= 0.0 x))
(assert (= y (/ 1.0 x)))
(check-sat)
```

Should this model be SAT or UNSAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SMT-LIB 2.0 and 2.5, all functions are total, so this example is SAT in SMT-LIB.  Both Z3 and CVC4 do indeed return SAT for the example in the question.

I found this counter-intuitive.  I think it would be mathematically more well justified to say that `y=1/x, x=0` is unsatisfiable in the reals.  In Mathematica, the equivalent code returns an empty list, indicating that no solution exists, i.e., `FindInstance[Element[x, Reals] && Element[y, Reals] && x == 0 && y == 1/x, {x, y}]` returns `{}`

Nonetheless, `/` [is defined this way in SMT-LIB](http://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/theories-Reals.shtml). So as far as Z3 or CVC4 are concerned, this problem is SAT.

Comment: Yes, that's how SMT defines those operators/functions. A recurring theme that always has exactly 50% supporters and 50% opponents :)

Comment: Thanks a lot Christoph.  I ran into this trying to figure out whether or not `(and (= y (^ x 0.5)) (< x 0.0))` should be SAT or UNSAT.  For consistency with the rest of SMT, I guess this sqrt example should also be SAT.  Now I just need to figure out how to get Z3 to actually give SAT for this sqrt example.