# How to represent logarithmic formula in z3py

Tags: z3, smt, z3py

I am very new to z3py. I am trying to code the following logarithmic expressions in z3py .

```
log(x,y)
```

I did search stack overflow a lot and came across a similar question, but unfortunately I could not get a satisfactory enough answer. Please help me!

Comment: What do you mean by `log(x,y)` as opposed to `log(x)`?  Is one of the arguments supposed to be the base?

Answer (score 1):

More generally, how can we define logs with Z3?

The only way I have gotten any traction at all is to use an approximate value for `e`, define `exp(x)` as `(^ e x)`, and then define `log` as a total function that is the inverse of `exp`.  In SMT-LIB 2:

```
(define-fun exp ((x Real)) Real (^ 2.718281828459045 x))
(declare-fun log (Real) Real)
(assert (forall ((x Real)) (= (log (exp x)) x)))
(assert (forall ((x Real)) (= (exp (log x)) x)))
```

In Z3Py:

```
from z3 import *
from math import e

# This is an approximation
def Z3_exp(x):
    return e ** x

s = Solver()

# We define Z3_log as a total function that is the inverse of Z3_exp
Z3_log = Function('log', RealSort(), RealSort())
x = Real('x')
s.add(ForAll([x], Z3_log(Z3_exp(x)) == x))
s.add(ForAll([x], Z3_exp(Z3_log(x)) == x))
```

The obvious problem with this is that it introduces an approximation for `e`, which will cause some incorrect results depending on what you are trying to prove.  Also, because it uses uninterpreted functions to define `log`, the most powerful nonlinear solver (nlsat) will not be used, and also, because [functions are total in SMT-LIB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38107558/y-1-x-x-0-satisfiable-in-the-reals), there will be the typical weird domain issues for negative arguments.

An alternative would be to simply bound `e`, but this is still not exact, and is likely to have worse behavior.  There is also an undocumented built-in symbol `euler` in Z3, but at the moment it is essentially non-functional.