# Is the QF_NRA logic in SMT-LIB decidable?

Tags: z3, smt, theorem-proving, cvc4

Is the QF_NRA logic in SMT-LIB decidable?

I know that Tarski proved that nonlinear arithmetic is decidable, in the sense that systems of polynomials in the real numbers are decidable. However, it's not obvious that QF_NRA falls under this umbrella, because QF_NRA contains division.  So the first question is whether or not division in QF_NRA includes division by variables where the denominator is potentially zero.  [I posted that as a separate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40182521/is-division-by-zero-included-in-qf-nra), because answering that turns out to be difficult enough all on its own.

If division by zero is not part of QF_NRA, then division in QF_NRA can be converted to multiplication, and the problem will be decidable as proven by Tarski.  If division is in fact included in QF_NRA, then I'm less sure.  My feeling is that the problem can still be broken up case-wise, with new variables introduced for the cases where division by zero occurs.  In this case QF_NRA would still be decidable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is decidable.

You can encode SMT-LIB division by treating division as an uninterpreted function that you axiomatize where needed, i.e. for each (/ t1 t2) appearing in the problem, you can add

```
t2 != 0 => t1 = (/ t1 t2)*t2  .
```

This in effect reduces the SMT-LIB theory of QF_NRA to the combination of two theories: reals (without division) and uninterpreted functions. Now, since both reals and uninterpreted functions are decidable theories in the quantifier-free fragment, you can rely on the classic arguments of Nelson and Oppen to show that the combination theory is decidable.

[Yices2](http://yices.csl.sri.com/), for example, can decide such combinations of reals and uninterpreted functions (based on MCSAT). Z3, as far as I know, can not combine reals and uninterpreted functions, and CVC4 does not yet have a decision procedure for the reals.

Comment: Isn't that axiomatization equivalent to just using `/` directly?

Comment: Thank you, your proposal for theory combination is a formalization of what I was imagining regarding handling the `t2 == 0` case separately from the `t2 != 0` case, the latter permitting the division to be eliminated, and the former being solvable in its own right, by introducing a new symbol for `(/ t1 t2)`.